# Prevent read() systemcall returing with 0 when run as background process

Tags: c, linux, background-process

I have a piece of software that is able to read commands from stdin for debug purposes in a separate thread. When my software runs as foreground process `read` behaves as expected, its blocking and waits for input by the user, i.e the thread sleeps.
When the software is run as a background process, `read` constantly returns `0` (possible EOF detected?).

The problem here is, that this specific read is in a `while(true)` loop. It runs as fast as it can and steals precious CPU load on my embedded device.

I tried redirecting `/dev/null` to the process but the behavior was the same. I am running my custom Linux on an ARM Cortex A5 board.

The problematic piece of code follows and is run inside its own thread:

```c
char bufferUserInput[256];
const int sizeOfBuffer = SIZE_OF_ARRAY(bufferUserInput);

while (1)
{

    int n = read(0, bufferUserInput, sizeOfBuffer); //filedes = 0 equals to reading from stdin
    printf("n is: %d\n", n);
    printf("Errno: %s",strerror(errno));

    if (n == 1)
    {
        continue;
    }

    if ((1 < n)
            && (n < sizeOfBuffer)
            && ('\n' == bufferUserInput[n - 1]))
    {
        printf("\r\n");
        bufferUserInput[n - 1] = '\0';
        ProcessUserInput(&bufferUserInput[0]);
    } else
    {
        n = 0;
    }
}
```

I am looking for a way to prevent `read` from constantly returning when running in the background and wait for user input (which of course will never come).

Comment: The posted code will also fail to properly handle input if it's invoked with a file as input, as with `app < input.txt`.  In that case, `read()` will fill `bufferUserInput` entirely and your code will then discard that input because `n` will equal `sizeOfBuffer`.  Also, `read()` returns `ssize_t`, not `int`.

Comment: A file will never be the input, its just there for short debug commands to read out values. You a right about the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `stdin` is not a terminal, `read` is returning with 0 because you are at the end of the file.  `read` only blocks after reading all available input when there *could* be more input in the future, which is considered to be possible for terminals, pipes, sockets, etc. but not for regular files nor for `/dev/null`.  (Yes, another process could make a regular file bigger, but that possibility isn't considered in the specification for `read`.)

Ignoring the various problems with your read loop that other people have pointed out (which you should fix *anyway*, as this will make reading debug commands from the user more reliable) the simplest change to your code that will fix the problem you're having right now is: check on startup whether stdin is a terminal, and don't launch the debug thread if it isn't.  You do that with the [`isatty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) function, declared in `unistd.h`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
// ...

int main(void)
{
    if (isatty(fileno(stdin)))
      start_debug_thread();
    // ...
}
```

(Depending on your usage context, it might also make sense to run the debug thread when `stdin` is a pipe or a socket, but I would personally not bother, I would rely on `ssh` to provide a remote (pseudo-)terminal when necessary.)

Comment: Thank you, this fixes my general problem but I'm still wondering why `read` is returning with `0`. I tested @PSkocik code snippet and got the same result.

Comment: `read` is returning with 0 because you are at the end of the file.  `read` only blocks after reading all available input when there _could_ be more input in the future, which is possible for terminals, pipes, sockets, etc. but not for files nor for `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 2):

If you start your program in the "background" (as `./program &`) from a shell *script*, it's stdin will be redirected from `/dev/null` (with some [exceptions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/523516/308316)).

Trying to read from `/dev/null` will always return 0 (EOF).

Example (on linux):

```
sh -c 'ls -l /proc/self/fd/0 & wait'
... -> /dev/null

sh -c 'dd & wait'
... ->  0 bytes copied, etc
```

The fix from the link above should also work for you:

```
#! /bin/sh
...
exec 3<&0
./your_program <&3 &
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`read()` doesn't return 0 when reading from the terminal in a backgrounded process.
It either continues to block while causing a `SIGTTIN` to be sent to the process (which may break the blocking and cause `retval=-1,errno=EINTR` to be returned or it causes `retval=-1, errno EIO` if `SIGTTIN` is ignore.

The snippet below demonstrates this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
int main()
{
    char c[256];
    ssize_t nr;

    signal(SIGTTIN,SIG_IGN);
    nr = read(0,&c,sizeof(c));
    printf("%zd\n", nr);
    if(0>nr) perror(0);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

The code snippet you've shown can't possibly test reveal 0-returns since you never test for zero-ness in the return value.

Comment: After the `read` I check the value of `n` and `errno` in the quick debug version. There I get n is: 0 and Errno: Success. I added the two debug lines in my code snippet

Comment: @J.Panek I made my snippet read 256 bytes just as your does (the change makes no difference in the behavior). When I compile and do `./a.out &` I get `Stopped` if the `SIG_IGN` line is commented out and  `Input/output error` otherwise. I never get return value `0` if the input is a terminal and the process is backgrounded. If you do, please post concrete steps on how to reproduce such behavior.

Comment: The software on the embedded device is started via startup script in `/etc/init.d` it redirects `stdout` and `stderr` into two log files. I tested your code snippet with a `while(1)` around the read block and get the same behavior, i.e. my log file is full of `0` and the CPU load is at 100%